# Python: exit while calling function

Tags: python, function, scope, exit

is their a way to exit out of nested functions while calling another function? I have a large-ish project that I am working on and want a function I can call from anywhere that leaves the scope off all nested functions and executes its commands

simplified example:

```
def foo():
    print("foo")
    bar()
    print("DO NOT PRINT THIS")

def bar():
    print("bar")
    exit(); baz() # leave scope of foo and call baz, results in "DO NOT PRINT THIS" not being printed

def baz():
    print("baz")

foo()
```

desired output:

```
foo
bar
baz
```

I am aware that I can use returns and if statements however that is somewhat unfeasible in my program, is their anyway I can achieve this?

Comment: `exit` exits the entire process, also you don't have nested functions, you just call a function inside another function

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "want a function I can call from anywhere that leaves the scope off all nested functions and executes its commands" Putting aside the terminology problems, *no, you don't*. You are fundamentally trying to organize the code in a way that doesn't make sense. The *entire point* of using a function is that, when it's done, it will `return` back to where it was called; and "where it was called" will pick up where it left off, possibly making use of a returned value.

Comment: My best guess - based on having seen the code of many beginners before - is that your "large-ish project" is something like an adventure game, where you want each function to represent a "room" or "location". This approach is fundamentally flawed.

Comment: You want to write functions that represent *what happens when you go to* a room. Do not use function calls to represent "going to" a room. Instead, have a main loop that uses some kind of data to represent the player's location; use that data to decide which "what happens" function to call; and use the return value from that function to indicate where the player may go next. When the user chooses a destination, update the location and loop again until an end state is reached.